# Openlayers legend

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

I need to create symbols for my vector layers. I have dynamic styles for my vector layers and I want to create legend for example in canvas or svg. 
Does anyone know any possibilities how can I render symbol for my legend based on ol.style?

Answer (score 1):

We did this in GeoExt 3 recently, have a look at the code (https://github.com/geoext/geoext3/blob/master/src/component/FeatureRenderer.js) and the example (http://rawgit.com/geoext/geoext3/master/examples/renderer/renderer.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have few more questions. As I saw posted example you are doing for every symbol new ol3 map. Did you tested to render legend for many symbols? Do you have any performance issues? I was looking maybe for little bit another solution to build custom canvas renderer only for symbols without map...